# Putting a break in between three different strings

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have three variables that are strings. However they sit one on top of the other with no spacing. Is there any way to add what would be equivalent to a 
 in the ts file and not the template. Or am I able to add multiple values to my angular component input and somehow break it up there? I am not certain on how to achieve this. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

.ts file

```
this.myContent= this.content.paragraph1 + this.content.paragraph2 + this.content.paragraph3;
```

.html file

```
            <my-component [myContent]="myContent"></my-component>
```

Comment: wrap your strings in spans, give those spans a class. apply css to class

Comment: I believe adding "\n" between your string variables might let you add newlines between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can use inline template literal. So you could assign `this.myContent` like this

```
this.myContent = `${this.content.p1}\n${this.content.p2}\n${this.content.p3}`
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following approach:

- Make `this.myContent` an array, and put `this.content.paragraph1`, `this.content.paragraph2` and so on in it.
- Put an `*ngIf` on `<my-component>`, and only display it if the content array has elements in it.
- Put a `<p *ngFor="...">` element within `<my-component>`, and iterate through the content array.

This will display the paragraphs, and will break them up.